# Change cainfo and cafile before each start PHP

Tags: php, curl, ini

I have a dynamic program with a separate bin, and I need to set the path to `curl-ca-bundle.crt` before each run, I tried to use this code

```
$real_path = Helper::getBinDirectory() . '\curl-ca-bundle.crt';
ini_set('curl.cainfo', $real_path);
ini_set('openssl.cafile', $real_path);

Logger::getLogger()->log( ini_get('curl.cainfo'));
Logger::getLogger()->log(ini_get('openssl.cafile'));
```

When outputting, `ini_get` gives the path that was originally written in `php.ini`, and not the one I wrote through `ini_set`. What to do?

P.S. If you change the path in `php.ini` to the path from `$real_path` everything works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These values (`curl.cainfo` and `openssl.cafile`) cannot be configured through scripts. These can only be changed in php.ini or httpd.conf.

This is documented at the following PHP docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.configuration.php#ini.curl.cainfo
https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.configuration.php

The "Changable" columns corresponds to the following modes: https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php